# In ARM big.LITTLE architecture is there any ID register to find how many core/cpu present in a cluster dynamically?

Tags: arm

Want to detect how many CPU/Core present in a cluster dynamically. Is there any ID register which support this in ARM big.LITTLE architecture?

Answer (score 1):

I think this information is available in the CPU ID Register.
If you havent found this already, its available at
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0360e/CACEDHJG.html

Comment: I understand MPIDR/MPIDR_EL0 register provide cluster number & cpu number in the cluster for the current CPU. My query can we get how many CPU present in a cluster dynamically from current CPU?

Comment: I'm also looking for this, but I don't want to make a kernel driver just to get this info. Could I get it using only inline assembly in a userspace script? Meanwhile I've been looking into `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuX/topology/physical_package_id` which seems to map exactly to my architecture, but I'm not sure if it's valid as a cluster identification.